# Updating the state of a Subcomponent in a list of Components when text input changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The component tree of my application is this one:

`App.js`

|

`Signs.js`

|

`Sign.js`

My `App.js` parent class has a list of objects in his state. Every object has this form:

`{id: 1, name: "signName", ranking: "good", description: "Some description"}`

The list of objects is described by the `Signs.js` component and each element of the list is represented by the `Sign.js` component.

Each `Sign.js` component has `<textarea>` input field in order to modify the description of the sign.

I would like to change the description of the object in the list in the state of `App.js` component as soon as the user changes the input.

I don't understand how to do it since the `onChange` event of the `<textarea>` takes the event as a parameter but i need to pass the sign as well in order to understand which of the signs in the list is modified!

`App.js` component:

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    signs: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Aries",
        ranking: "Good",
        description: "Random description"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Taurus",
        ranking: "Good",
        description: "Random description"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Gemini",
        ranking: "Good",
        description: "Random description"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = (event, sign) => {
    const signs = [...this.state.signs];
    const index = signs.indexOf(sign);
    signs[index] = { ...sign };
    signs[index].description = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ signs });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Signs
          signs={this.state.signs}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Signs.js` component:

```js
const Signs = ({ signs, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {signs.map(sign => (
        <Sign key={sign.id} sign={sign} onChange={onChange} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Sign.js` component:

```js
const Sign = ({ sign, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <h3>{sign.name}</h3>
      </div> 
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <textarea
          onChange={() => onChange(sign)}
          value={sign.description}
        >
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `onChange={e => onChange(e,sign)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the event to `onChange`:

```
//                v Accepts event
handleChange = (event, sign) => {...}

const Sign = ({ sign, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <h3>{sign.name}</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
//                                        v Pass the event
        <textarea onChange={e => onChange(e, sign)} value={sign.description} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-58766360-event]

> Side note: Be aware that you using ["prop-drilling"](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) (anti-pattern) when the application grows you may want to use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api).